# Jquery Datatables multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a dropdown with multiple options that initializes a datatable using javascript. Everything works fine but the problem comes when i have two json data that i want to show as shown below , please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1y0kmfo/6/)

---

```
Chelsea Goalkepeers
______________________________________________________________________________
playerName    | Player Club |  Player Value  | player Points

______________________________________________________________________________
Chelsea Defenders
______________________________________________________________________________
playerName    | Player Club |  Player Value  | player Points
```

and here is the code

HTML

```
<select id="playersFilter">
    <option>Choose Players</option>
    <option value="gk">goalkepeers</option>
    <option value="def">Defenders</option>
     <option value="Chelsea">Chelsea</option>
</select>
<table class="display" id="players"></table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var goalkepeers = [{
    "playerName": "Mignolet",
    "playerClub": "Liverpool",
    "playerValue": "5.0",
    "playerPoints": "89"
}, {
    "playerName": "de Gea",
    "playerClub": "Manchester",
    "playerValue": "6.7",
    "playerPoints": "120"
}];
var defenders = [{
    "playerName": "Ivanovic",
    "playerClub": "Chelsea",
    "playerValue": "7.8",
    "playerPoints": "100"
}, {
    "playerName": "Mertesacker",
    "playerClub": "Arsenal",
    "playerValue": "7.7",
    "playerPoints": "110"
}];

var chelseaKeepers= [{
    "playerName": "Courtois",
    "playerClub": "chelsea",
    "playerValue": "5.5",
    "playerPoints": "121"
}, {
    "playerName": "Begovic",
    "playerClub": "chelsea",
    "playerValue": "5.0",
    "playerPoints": "106"
}];

var chelseaDefenders= [{
    "playerName": "Ivanovic",
    "playerClub": "Chelsea",
    "playerValue": "7.8",
    "playerPoints": "100"
}, {
    "playerName": "Terry",
    "playerClub": "chelsea",
    "playerValue": "7.0",
    "playerPoints": "177"
}];

var aoColumns = [{
    "sTitle": "Name",
    "mDataProp": "playerName"
}, {
    "sTitle": "Club",
    "mDataProp": "playerClub"
}, {
    "sTitle": "Value",
    "mDataProp": "playerValue"
}, {
    "sTitle": "Points",
    "mDataProp": "playerPoints"
}];
var table = $('#players').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    "columns": aoColumns,
    "order": [
        [3, "desc"]
    ],
        "destroy": true
});
$("#playersFilter").change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value == "gk") {
        table.clear().rows.add(goalkepeers).draw();
    } else if (value == "def") {
        table.clear().rows.add(defenders).draw();
    } else {
        table.clear().draw();
    }
});
```

All i want is when the  option for team is selected the data to be displayed as shown above. Any help please...

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Your fiddle was busted. I just Fixed your errors : https://jsfiddle.net/x1y0kmfo/6/

Comment: @duffymo , click the fiddle u will see all the codes...

Comment: @ReaganGallant , first i was not getting any errors , second the issue isn't fixed in your fiddle , all i want is when you choose chelsea option the json data with chelseaKeepers and chelseaDefenders to be displayed as shown in my question, that's all i want , thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do the grouping yourself. I don't have time for that now. View the datatable documentation and look for Row grouping:

UPDATED:
A better solution would be this:

```
else if(value= "Chelsea")
{
    table.clear().rows.add(chelseaKeepers.concat(chelseaDefenders)).draw();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x1y0kmfo/24/

Comment: Or concatenate the two arrays...?

Comment: @annoyingmouse i implemented you suggested.Check the updated code.